# How do you change (by .configuration?) the tintColor, when the button is depressed, in a custom/filled UIButton?

Tags: swift, uikit, uibutton

Pls note that this question is about tintColor. This question has no relation to backgroundColor, which is totally different. Also, I notice there are many QA about the tintColor *of an image on* a button. This has nothing to do with that. This a question is about the property `.tintColor` of a `UIButton`

Have a typical (modern-day) button,

```
private lazy var toggle: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton(type: .custom)
    v.configuration = .filled()
    v.configuration?.titleTextAttributesTransformer =
    UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { i in
        var o = i
        o.font = UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .medium)
        return o
    }
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    v.layer.cornerCurve = .continuous
    v.layer.borderWidth = 1
    v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemYellow.cgColor
    v.clipsToBounds = true
    v.setTitle("Log", for: [])
    v.setTitleColor(.systemGray3, for: [])
    v.tintColor = .systemGray
    ...
```

Note that the tintColor is system gray.

How the heck do you set the color to which the tintColor changes, when the button is depressed?

To express that bette:  how do you (ideally using configuration) make the tintColor chaneg to some other specified color when the state changes?

Comment: If you set the text and background color transformers correctly, the tint color never appears. So why do you care what the tint color is? Where in the button are you looking?

Comment: "but the transparent looks horrible depending on what it's floating over." If your button is floating over something, it's probably better to give the button a non-transparent background. And after you do that, it won't look horrible anymore.

Comment: "can you just turn off the color-change-effect when it is depressed" Yes you can. But I can't tell you about it because you have not explained _what part of the button is changing color_.

Comment: "If you set the text and background color transformers correctly, the tint color never appears. So why do you care what the tint color is? "  Cheers @matt did you mean "you never need to use the tintColor" ?  I don't know what "correctly" means but regardless of how you set the background color, you will see the tint color. Also, you must know that the tint color affects more than just the background right? (Even thought that's all i mention in the Q)

Comment: I've removed the "speculative guesses" at the end of the question so that it's clearer what the question is (ie, "How do you change (by .configuration?) the color to which the tintColor changes, when the button is depressed, in a custom/filled UIButton?")

Comment: Ok so you are not talking about the tint color at all. You're talking about the background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it turns out you are not talking about the tint color at all. You're talking about the background color.

Set the configuration's `background.backgroundColor` to a fixed color, and it will stay fixed.

For more flexibility (eg a different color while pressing), set *instead* the configuration's `background.backgroundColorTransformer`.

Comment: "I'm asking about the .tintColor" I asked you where you think you see this color. You said you saw it as the fill color. I'm telling you how to govern that color. I've told you in detail. Try it. You can keep reverting to the tint color all you like but what I'm saying to do does stabilize the color of the button. I'd forget about the tint color if I were you.

Comment: No, it isn't. If you set up your configuration based button properly the way I'm telling you, it isn't used at all. It was used in the earlier type of button, and it still exists, but if you want to take control of the colors you see in the button you won't use the tint color for anything. Do not try to live in both the past and the present. If you're going to use button configurations then use them fully. That is my answer. Take it or leave it. We use only configuration based buttons in our app, and believe me, I am in total control of all their colors.

Comment: Ahh!  I'm essentially learning that tintColor is becoming let's say legacy'ed. This is great information.  the hierarchical nature of tintColor still seems to be in play. I'm going to have to read the damn manual :/ THanks again ..

Comment: Note too that the color change you are seeing _does not involve any change in the tint color._ The runtime creates its own variations on the tint color, for different button states. But if you say e.g. `v.configuration?.background.background.backgroundColor = v.tintColor` it will stop doing that. The same is true for the title text color and the image color; by supplying your own colors and configurations, _you_ control this behavior. That's the whole point.